# Library or code to do Marker Code or Watermark Code error correction

Tags: error-correction, forwarderrorcorrection

Is anyone aware of any libraries or freely available code to encode/decode Marker Codes or Watermark Codes?  I don't really care about the language as long as it can run on a normal Linux box.

Any references to programs which can do Watermark/Marker error correcting codes would also be great.  So far all I can find are papers on the subject, which don't release their source code, or provide demo programs.

In general, I'm looking for insertion/deletion aware error correcting codes.